# Make R project Automatically open Specific Scripts

Tags: r, file, rstudio, project

I am working in team, we mainly use R, I am quite used to use R project in Rstudio, which I like because when I open them I have all my scripts and everything at the right place. However when another member of the team opens one of my project it loads the values and data but does not open the R script (one can see that by physically clicking on the project through the windows explorer rather than using the menu at the top right in R). I guess something can be done in the .Rprofile but I did not find any command to open physically a script, I tried

```
file.edit("./Main.R")
```

but it did not open anything. It just got me the message :

> Error: could not find function "file.edit"

As always,
Thanks for your help !

**EDIT
I tried to use

```
file.show
file.edit 
shell.exec(file.path(getwd()), "Main.R"))
```

in the .Rprofile. Nothing worked.

Romain

Comment: You could you `source()` to read the R code from your specific R script.

Comment: `source()` reads the code, but I want to open the script physically, so that the user can modify it. So I am afraid it does not do the trick, except if I am missing something here...

Comment: there is `edit(filename)` but it is not clear the real context of the question. Do you want to open the file in Rstudio?

Comment: Yes, basically what I want is that double clicking on the R project from windows explorer gives the same result as choosing the project from the top right menu in R studio. In other words, being able to physically open in R studio a list of scripts when one click on the R project from the explorer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code in the .Rprofile file.

```
setHook("rstudio.sessionInit", function(newSession) {
  if (newSession)
    rstudioapi::navigateToFile('<file name>', line = -1L, column = -1L)
}, action = "append")
```

The rstudioapi library has the function navigateToFile to open a file in Rstudio. The problem is that the code in the .Rprofile runs before Rstudio initialization. To deal with this problem you can use the setHook function (from base package) to make the code execute after the Rstudio initialization.

Answer (score 1):

file.edit requires the utils package

```
library(utils)
file.edit("Master.R")
```

However, if it opens in Notepad rather than RStudio you have the same problem as me. I've tried editing the `editor=` in all possible places: .RProfile, RProfile, RProfile.sites, with and without `.First()` function statements and calls. However, RStudio does not load the .R file in RStudio if told to. It may be linked to the .RData file being loaded after .RProfile. Bug? Or at least a feature RStudio should incorporate in their RProject file specification.