# Workaround to open files via .Rprofile when loading a project in RStudio?

Tags: rstudio

This question is related to the (unsolved) [Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473205). I want students to be able to download an RStudio project from github and have the project open one or more scripts in the editor. .Rprofile works for other things, but a file.edit() command results in an error because the utils library is not loaded; apparently RStudio loads its own version of utils later on and replaces the editor. Explicitly loading utils and then calling file.edit() will crash RStudio.

I'm running out of ideas - a workaround could be to have .Rprofile trigger source()'ing an initialization script at a later time, *after* RStudio has finished loading, but I don't know if that is even possible. Any creative solutions?

Comment: Hi from RStudio. :-) There is no declarative way to do this, unfortunately, but I've written up a feature request for it since there seem to be some demand (RStudio already has a mechanism for it, it's just not exposed in a way you can leverage in this scenario).

Comment: Hi @Jonathan - I do think that would be useful. Note that these would actually be two feature requests: one, to have access to libraries from .Rprofile, the other, to be able to configure RStudio projects to load files on startup, perhaps even set focus. Either one would solve my problem. A fully general solution would include both. :-)

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56377233/66526

Comment: @Ryan - that looks like a solution! Thanks for posting the link to this thread.